# problems beginning an angular app from angular-seed

Tags: angularjs

I've completed a course on AngularJs through codecademy.  I followed the angular-seed steps to set up my own local environment to make my first app, but it appears angular is not initializing on my site.  I cant even evaluate a simple expression such as {{3+2}} let alone pull scope values from the controller.

my first steps:
1. clone angular seed from git
2. npm install into directory
3. npm start

my code:

index.html

```
    <html lang="en" ng-app='myApp'> 
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>My AngularJS App</title>

  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">

  <!-- core Bootstrap css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">


  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>


<!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/MainController.js"></script>

<!-- Directives -->
    <script src="js/listinginfo.js"></script>


</head>





<body ng-controller ='MainController'>

<div class ='container-fluid'>

<div class ='col-md-4'>

  <ul>
    <li class = 'text-primary'> Properties </li>
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>



  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->
<div class = 'col-md-8'>


          <p> {{ 3 + 2 }}</p>

</div>


    </div>





<!-- container--> </div>





<!-- for production use

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script> -->


</body>
```

and here is my module:

```
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

controller:

```
myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope) {


}
  ];
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks

my console errors in chrome  are :

```
Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: print, not all, (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-resolution: 120dpi)
http://localhost:8000/app/js/app.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8000/app/js/MainController.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8000/app/js/listinginfo.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
angular.js:4138 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
    at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
    at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1774:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1698:38)
    at module (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1772:14)
    at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4115:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4099:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4025:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1452:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1473:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…calhost%3A8000%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1473%3A12)
```

i figured cloning angular-seed and running npm install would setup everything correctly

Comment: Have you defined your controller logic anywhere?

Comment: need to use browser console/dev tools to start debugging process ... errors thrwn? files not loaded?

Comment: controller is empty but defined, updated in op

Comment: controller has syntax problems, get rid of extra braces and `;`. Use a code linter to look for such issues

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard to tell without checking what errors are being thrown. Have you defined your controller though? Try adding a controller in your module like:

```
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}])
```

and remove

```
<!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/MainController.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to run your application without much overhead and it works. My files look something like this:

> index.html

```
  <html lang="en" ng-app='myApp'> 
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>My AngularJS App</title>

  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css"> -->

  <!-- core Bootstrap css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">


<!--   <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
   <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
   <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
   <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script> -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/MainController.js"></script>

<!-- Directives -->
    <script src="js/listinginfo.js"></script>


</head>





<body ng-controller ='MainController'>

<div class ='container-fluid'>

<div class ='col-md-4'>

  <ul>
    <li class = 'text-primary'> Properties </li>
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>



  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->
<div class = 'col-md-8'>


          <p> {{ 3 + 2 }}</p>

</div>


    </div>





<!-- container--> </div>





<!-- for production use

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script> -->


</body>
```

> app.js

```
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

> MainController.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}])
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server may not have access to read the js files inside your bower_components/angular folder. This has happened to me when one time.

Also like the above comment look at your browser console to see what kind of errors you see. Is MainController defined?